# How to get owner name from of accounts & opportunities

Tags: apex, soql, community, opportunity

Hi friends i'm new to development i got a requirement like to get account owner names and opportunities owner names from cases.So i tried to write a soql query to get for specific record type in cases.

So sample query like

`SELECT Id,Account.owner.name,RecordTypeId FROM Case where RecordTypeId ='01290000001HpJp'`

But my problem is how to get both opportunity owners names and account owners names in a single soql query.

Comment: Is your case linked to opportunity ? Do you have an opportunity lookup to case ?

Comment: An account can have multiple opportunities .How would you know which opportunity owner you need

Comment: Ya i know we filtered the opportunities based on some fields.But i want to know how to retrieve owner names right now. @MohithShrivastava

Comment: The question is whether or not you have some way of indicating a particular Opportunity on the Case record. Do you have a lookup field on the Case object that allows you to indicate an Opportunity or are you relying on the Account field to then get all of the owner names for all the Opportunities associated with that Account?

Comment: Hey right now in my org there is no lookup with opportunity.But i got requirement.So i tried to do with account and for other requirement i need account owners also.So how to retrieve account owner names and opportunity owner names.you have any suggestions @sfdcJameson

Comment: Exhorting us that you need help *now* is not very polite. Telling us that you have to follow requirements and can't change that they conflict doesn't help either. You need to resolve the conflict pointed out by @Mohith before anyone can help you. One common scheme would be to use the newest record, but it's not a question we can answer for you.

Comment: Sorry But i had already answered to Mohit shrivastava. After that i came up with scenario in my org.Actually  i'm new to development.They don't want to set up a look up field in cases with opportunity. So i came with apex and soql. @Adrian Larson